# MySQL Inner join output to html table in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, join

I have a table that is being displayed in a form, which looks like this: http://puu.sh/5VBBv.png

[image]

The end of the table, City, is displaying an ID of a city, which is supposed to be linked to another table (http://puu.sh/5VBIG.png).

[image]

What I've done for my INNER JOIN query is:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cities INNER JOIN people ON people.cityid = cities.id") or die(mysql_error());`
```

and I'm trying to output it into a table:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['cityid'] . "</td>";
```

My issue is that I'm not quite sure how to actually display the cityid that corresponds to the city name. I've tried using ['name'] and other values as the value to output in the table, and I can't find any solution for this anywhere so far. I'm just learning joins, so I don't exactly have any knowledge on what I could be doing wrong. Is there anything immensely obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your use of `*` in the join query could be ambiguous. If cities had a name column and people had a name column, you won't know which one you're getting. Second you can do this a couple ways. I think you're trying to get a city id from a city name. If that's correct you can either make and ajax call and query it directly or define an array as follow:

```
$res = mysql_query("...");    
$city_ids = Array();

while ($ary = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        city_ids[$ary['name']] = Ary['id']; 
}
```

Then when you get the name, you just loop up `$ary['name']`.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting from people and joining cities makes more sense. Then select the fields you need.

```
SELECT people.*, cities.name as city_name FROM people JOIN cities ON people.cityid = cities.id
```

Then, `echo $row['city_name']`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select ID from cities city, people person where person.ID = city.ID
```

You are selecting the ID from both Cities and People, and joining on the ID

Comment: Unknown column 'city.cityid' in 'where clause', I see what you're trying to do but I'm not sure how to correctly format that

Comment: Sorry, I went to bed after I posted this comment.

Updated and a bit explained